# Overloaded operator with exception handling

Tags: c++, oop, exception

> I have a class *Matrice* with 2d-array as a member. I have overloaded the operator `==` to check if 2 *Matrice* are equal and I was curious if I can apply and exception handling to `throw` if the
> number of columns for first obj isn't equal to second OR number of lines , and that's what I have done.

```
 bool operator==(const Matrice& m, const Matrice& n)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    try
    {
        if (m._nrL != n._nrL || m._nrC != n._nrC)
        {
            throw false;
        }

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < m._nrL; ++i)
            for (size_t j{ 0 }; j < m._nrC; ++j)
                if (m._elemente[i][j] != n._elemente[i][j])
                    return false;
        return true;    
    }

    catch (bool& err)
    {
        std::cerr << "\nVerificarea egalitatii dintre cele doua matrice nu este posibila!";
    }
}
```

> In my main i tried to check if the operator is working.

```
    Matrice a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a;

    Matrice b;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << b;

    std::cout << (a == b);
```

> When I compile it with different number of columns or lines for the arrays, it gives me something like:
> `Verificarea egalitatii dintre cele doua matrice nu este posibila!214`

> I used debug and it shows me a true(214) that is displayed. I put `return false` in `catch()`, and now it displays me:
> `Verificarea egalitatii dintre cele doua matrice nu este posibila!false`.

> Finally my question is, it is possible to modify the code for `operator==` so that it doesn't display `false` anymore?

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. Please [edit] your question and focus on a single question that can have a single, well-defined answer. In general: C++ allows you to throw an exception any time.

Comment: the `true` / `false` output is from `std::cout << (a == b);` not from within the `operator==`.

Comment: You could make the `Matrix` class a template, where the number of rows and columns are template arguments. Then a matrix like `Matrix<2, 4>` is a different type from `Matrix<4, 2>`.

Comment: Your `operator==` should EITHER throw an exception and let the calling function deal with it, or silently return false. Printing errors from `operator==` is not expected behavior.

Comment: Or if the matrix sizes should be configurable at run-time, then I'm not sure an exception would the right way to handle size mismatches. Instead just return `false`? But if you want to use exceptions then just thrown a proper exception (preferably inherited from `std::exception`) and 
*don't* catch it. Instead you let the caller (the code doing the comparison) handle such errors. The `==` operator should *not* print error messages (it's not the expected behavior of `==`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want this line of code

```
std::cout << (a == b);
```

to throw an exception in case something went wrong instead of printing something then you need to make that line of code throw an exception. Sounds reasonable, no ;).

Your `operator==` throws and exception and immediately catches it, hence the exception never leaves the `operator==` and therefore it has undefined behavior for not returning a `bool` on all paths.

I think instead you want:

```
bool operator==(const Matrice& m, const Matrice& n)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    if (m._nrL != n._nrL || m._nrC != n._nrC)
    {
        throw false;
    }

    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < m._nrL; ++i)
        for (size_t j{ 0 }; j < m._nrC; ++j)
            if (m._elemente[i][j] != n._elemente[i][j])
                return false;
    return true;           
}
```

And then

```
try {
    std::cout << (a == b);
} catch (bool& err) {
    std::cerr << "\nVerificarea egalitatii dintre cele doua matrice nu este posibila!";
}
```

By the way, you should inherit from one of the standard exception base classes. Throwing a `bool` is a little surprising.

Comment: I was trying to see if it s possible to use try, catch in the definition of the operator==

Comment: @Dragoș-GeorgeGherasim yes thats what your code does, but thats not what you want when you want `std::cout << (a==b);` to print nothing in case of an exception. Also there is the issue of undefined behavior for not returning something

Comment: @Dragoș-GeorgeGherasim as SomeDude mentioned in a comment, it is rather pointless to throw an excpetion just to catch it immediately, the calling code doesnt know about the exception.

Comment: I didn't prefere to have try and catch in main until I saw that s a bad behavior not having them, but I understood what did u say and I will use your exemple. Thank you !!